# Assign products to category programatically in magento2

Tags: magento2, product, category

How can I assign 'New products' to 'NEW PRODUCTS category' programatically in magento 2.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to get category Ids and product Id to set data:
impliment this :

```
$this->getCategoryLinkManagement()->assignProductToCategories(
                $product->getSku(),
                $product->getCategoryIds()
            );
```

also impliment this function :

```
private function getCategoryLinkManagement()
{
    if (null === $this->categoryLinkManagement) {
        $this->categoryLinkManagement = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get('Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface');
    }
    return $this->categoryLinkManagement;
}
```

rest dependency you should manage for : `Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface`

intialize :

```
protected $categoryLinkManagement;
```

> > Direct use of \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance() is not valid as per magento so you can inject it in Constructor
> >
> > This answer is for below magento 2.2 versions, so please take a note

Comment: I used this code in a block  and tried to render that block in template file. When I tried this method I got "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function assignProductToCategories()" in the template file.  Could you please help me to sort out this?

Comment: Have you give dependency for **"Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface"** ?

Comment: Yes, I have added. I worked fine.

Comment: Hi @RonakChauhan I tried your code but it doesnt seem like working . My products are not getting assigned to category..

Comment: @Daniel_12 are you getting any error?

Comment: @RonakChauhan i'm getting error https://i.stack.imgur.com/CL36v.png
magento version 2.2.7
Could you help?

Comment: Hi, Please tell me the full block code to implement the above one.

Answer (score 23):

I think, this needs an updated answer which does not make use of the object manager. Also, there are some kinks involved which are not mentioned anywhere.

In your constructor, inject the CategoryLinkManagementInterface:

```
protected $categoryLinkManagement;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface $categoryLinkManagementInterface,
    ...
) {
    $this->categoryLinkManagement = $categoryLinkManagementInterface;
    ...
}
```

Later in your code, assign categories the following way:

```
$product = $this->productRepository->getById(1337); // or any other way to get a product model/interface
$categoryIds = [
    42,
    606
];
$this->categoryLinkManagement->assignProductToCategories(
    $product->getSku(),
    $categoryIds
);
```

This will replace all previous category assignments. If you want to keep the existing category assignments, use something like this:

```
$categoryIds = array_unique(
    array_merge(
        $product->getCategoryIds(),
        $categoryIds
    )
);
```

**Be aware**: The link management defers the category assignment (for the product attribute) to the scheduled indexer. This means that if you make other changes to the product and save it after assignProductToCategories()

```
$product = $this->productRepository->save($product);
```

the category assignments will be gone as $product contains either null (if it was a newly created product) or only the previously assigned categories for its attribute. Also,

```
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($product->getId());
```

right after assignProductToCategories() will not help for the same reason mentioned above. Either assign categories at the latest possible point in time (when you do not save the product afterwards) or assign the attribute manually before saving again

```
$product->setCategoryIds($categoryIds);
```

If you opt to use the latter, you could probably fall back to only using setCategoryIds(). I have not tested either case (assignProductToCategories + setCategoryIds + save or setCategoryIds only + save) for performance impact, so I can not comment on that, but I think the whole circumstance was important to mention.

Comment: hi, @Drelling, Could not save product \"41859\" with position 0 to category 8  getting above error,

Comment: Hi @jafarpinjar, is that all you got in terms of error messages? I could think of a few reasons, why this occured:
1. You accidentally used $product->getId() instead of $product->getSku()
2. The product's URL key is not unique (although I think that the error message would be specific)
3. The product is already assigned to category with id 8

Comment: 1. can we not use $product->getId()? 3. The product is already assigned to category with id 8 – T. if assigned can we not remove it?

Comment: 1. No, assignProductToCategories() explicitly needs the SKU, not the ID! If that was your error, try again with SKU instead.
3. Ah, I was somewhat wrong here. The error I was thinking of occurs when $categoryIds would contain the same category more than once. You actually need to include category id 8 to keep it in that category. If you don't, it will be removed. So that's how you can remove a product from a category.

Comment: The error I was thinking of occurs when $categoryIds would contain the same category more than once. Its not possible is it? because category id is unique, I am passing sku only to this method assignProductToCategories not the id

Comment: "category id is unique" Exactly. That is why I was using array_unique() when you merge existing categories with the categories you want to add a product to.

"I am passing sku only to this method assignProductToCategories" Yes, the function needs the product's sku, not the product id. The reason is not the category id being unique, though. The magento developers just decided, that this function should receive the sku, not the id. No idea why.

Comment: Worked for me too

Answer (score 9):

**Assign Products To Category**

```
 <?php
 $new_category_id = array('100','101');
 $sku = 'sku of product';

 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

 $CategoryLinkRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface');
 $CategoryLinkRepository->assignProductToCategories($sku, $new_category_id);
```

**Remove Products From Category**

```
 <?php
 $category_id = 101;
 $sku = 'sku of product';

 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

 $CategoryLinkRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryLinkRepository');
 $CategoryLinkRepository->deleteByIds($category_id ,$sku);
```

Comment: getting this error, Could not save product with position 0 to category 8

Comment: @jafarpinjar this error is related to other customization. If you check this code snippet with fresh Magento install, it will work well. Please check if any third party customization preventing this code from execution

Comment: hi @chirag dodia, no, I have used this code in custom file and running it by moving to root folder, no customization is used

Comment: @jafarpinjar try with fresh product and check is this something related to a particular product?

Comment: hi @chirag, i got this error, Could not save product \"41859\" with position 0 to category 8

Comment: its take too long time, not recommended

Answer (score 5):

Even if the question was answered already, I'd like to add a faster way to assign a group of products to a category, as iterating `$this->getCategoryLinkManagement()->assignProductToCategories()` is quite slow

This alternative involves loading the category we want our group of products to be assigned to, so we need to inject `Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory`, we can set a group of products to the category using `setPostedProducts()` which takes an array of `['entity_id','position']` so a code example would be something like this:

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory;
...
protected $_category;
...
$this->_category = $categoryFactory;

    $parentsCollection = $this->_productCollection->create()
        ->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',['in' => $data['parent_ids']]);

    $parentsPosted = array_fill_keys(array_keys($parentsCollection->toArray(['entity_id'])), 0);

    if($catIds == 80 || $catIds == 82) {
        $category = $this->_category->create()->load($catIds);
        $category->setPostedProducts($parentsPosted);
        $category->save();
        echo "Products assigned to category: ".$catIds."\n";
    }
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = ObjectManager::getInstance();
$catalogProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$catalogProduct->setSku('sku-1');
$catalogProduct->setName('name');
$catalogProduct->setAttributeSetId(4);
$catalogProduct->setStatus(1); // Status on product enabled/ disabled 1/0
$catalogProduct->setVisibility(4);
$catalogProduct->setTypeId('simple'); // type of product (simple/virtual/downloadable/configurable)
$catalogProduct->setPrice(100);

$catalogProduct->setCategoryIds(['id']); // here you are

$catalogProduct->setStockData([
    'is_in_stock' => true,
    'qty'         => 10
]);

$catalogProduct->setStoreId(1); // $this->storeManagerInterface->getStore()->getId()
$catalogProduct->setWebsiteIds([1]); // $this->storeManagerInterface->getStore()->getWebsiteId()

$catalogProduct->save();
```

Comment: This is a very heavy request and executes very slowly as oppose to Link Manager

Answer (score 0):

> getCategoryIds() why we use CategoryIds()

Comment: Is this supposed to be a question or answer?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use position to assign product in category**

```php
namespace Vendor\Namespace\Controller\Adminhtml\Category;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Setpos extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\File\Csv $csvProcessor
    ) {
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_csvProcessor = $csvProcessor;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $cateId = 41;
        try {
            $file = 'dir1/dir2/filename.csv';
            if(isset($file) {
                $csvFields = $this->_csvProcessor->getData($file);
                $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($cateId);
                $products = $category->getProductsPosition();
                $count=0;
                foreach ($csvFields as $row => $csvField) 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (is_numeric(trim($csvField[1])))
                        {
                            $_products = $this->_productRepository->get(trim($csvField[0]));
                            $products[$_products->getId()] = trim($csvField[1]);  
                            $count++;                   
                        }
                    }catch (\Exception $e) {
                        echo $e->getMessage().'Get some erron in '.trim($csvField[0]);
                    }
                }
                $category->setPostedProducts($products);
                $category->save();
                if(!empty($errorSku))
                echo __('SKU '.implode(",",$errorSku).' .... were not updated. Please check if the sku exist.');   
                echo __($count.' Products have been successfully updated.');
            }
            else {
                echo __('CSV file not uploaded properly, please try again!');
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Please try the code below to update the category of a product.**

```
protected $categoryLinkManagement;

public function __construct(
    ............................................................................
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface $categoryLinkManagement,
    ............................................................................
) {
    ............................................................................
    $this->categoryLinkManagement = $categoryLinkManagement;
    ............................................................................
}

............................................................................
............................................................................
............................................................................

public function updateCategoryId($productColl, $categoryId)
{
    $categoryId = 23;
    $categoryIds = array_unique(
        array_merge(
            $productColl->getCategoryIds(),
            [$categoryId]
        )
    );
    $this->categoryLinkManagement->assignProductToCategories($productColl->getSku(), $categoryIds);
}
```

Here, `$productColl` is the product object, and `$categoryId` contains the new category ID value.