# Adding Product to Category on selecting yes/no attribute in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, product-attribute

I want to add a product to my 'On Sale' category when the system admin selects the 'On Sale' yes/no attribute in Magento 2. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: you need to use plugin or observer after product save and use below link to assign product to category

Comment: @VaibhavAhalpara Where's the link you are talking about?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140879/45422