# Assign product to category programmatically Magento2 receive an error

Tags: magento2, category-products

I'm trying assign product to categories using code like there [Assign products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140875/assign-products-to-category-programatically-in-magento2):

```
.........    
$this->categoryLinkManagement->assignProductToCategories(
            $product->getSku(),
            $catIds
        );
............
```

but receive an error

[image]

Is it magento2 bug ? i use version 2.2.7

Comment: Have you tried disabling flat categories?

Comment: Yes, I have, and it works, thanx