# Magento1.9.6 migrate Magneto2.3.3 after data migration getting issue

Tags: category, magento2.3.3, data-migration

I have done success fully data migration M1.9.6 to M2.3.3 after in admin side product inside category not assign default cateogry so any idea how to assign it automatically because our product data large and not manually selected.

Comment: let me know how many categories in your site ?

Comment: Have you tried to set programmatically using custom script https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140875/assign-products-to-category-programatically-in-magento2/140879  I recommend you to try with one single product & test the scenarios at backend and frontend if it works as expected, then try with all product collection & assign the product to a respected category programmatically.

Comment: @NagarajuK Thnaks for reply but there 50k plus product in our website and how to assign only default cateogry in admin side product edit after manually not possible so is it any other way

Comment: Programatically we have an option @rv singh do you have local instance?

Comment: Yes we have local instance

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to assign the products to root Categorie programmatically

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 800000);
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$rootCategoryId = array('2');//Root categorie Id here
//For single product
$sku = '24-MB01';
$categoryLinkRepository = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface');
$categoryLinkRepository->assignProductToCategories($sku, $rootCategoryId);
echo "successfully assigned to root categorie=".$sku;

//For all the products
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
foreach ($collection as $product){
    $categoryLinkRepository->assignProductToCategories($product->getSku(), $rootCategoryId);
    echo "successfully assigned to root categorie".$product->getSku();
}
?>
```

https://prnt.sc/qmutz1

https://prnt.sc/qmuu5n

**Note**: 1. Please make sure the test with a single product first then if it works as expected then you can try with the product collection on local instance.

2. I strongly recommend you do an experiment on your local instance first
3. Verify the frontend whether the product has been displaying or not.
4. Copy-paste & change the root Categorie Id  as per your website.
5. If you want you can add try/catch in the above script
6. Execute this script from the command line from the root directory of magento2
7. Once the script execution has done, do reindex & flush cache

Comment: Thanks for reply but if migrated data already in m2 inside so i have e to used for all data product inside cateogry by default cateogry selected

Comment: Did you know how to custom api module "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/300780/magento2-2-6-how-to-create-custom-api-module/300830#300830"

Comment: @RvSingh one small query is the above script is if works for you?

Comment: but actually  after migration in most of the product is not assign to root category so for that what i have to do?I know this is work ony one product but for multiple what can i do?